# Cython getting len of C++ object list

Tags: python, c++, cython

I have a Cython `foo.pyx` file and a corresponding c++ `foo.h` file.
Inside `foo.h` I have a list of `Foo` objects called `Foos` defined like this:

```
std::list<Foo> Foos;
```

Inside my `foo.pyx` Cython file I have an iterator which iterates over the list such as this:

```
it = engine.Foos.begin()
while it != engine.Foos.end():
    # Do stuff
```

The problem I am facing is I want to know *beforehand* how big `Foos` is. In regular python I would just call `len(foos)` however trying `len(engine.Foos)` or `len(it)` here just results in Cython throwing an error about not being able to convert to a Python object.

Is there any way to get the length of the c++ object list prior to iterating over it (note; I do NOT need a solution where I cound the number of iterations inside the while loop).

Comment: If you want to know "how big Foos is" then just use size() function: Foos.size()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `engine.Foos.size()`.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/size